# I am getting old push notifications from Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

The official Android app is giving me old push notifications. That's also in opposite order, meaning most recent one was pushed first. I am getting push messages every few minutes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The problem reported here and reported in my post does not show the same symptoms as the problem reported regarding the iOS app: in Android the notifications *never stopped working*.

Comment: Fair enough @Louis, retracted. Sadly enough, can't cast correct vote now. :(

Comment: Same problem here (Android 1.0.51)